# передача обьектов в функцию через this

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты, this

Итак, друзья, такая проблема:
Есть у меня обьект со случайно генерируемыми параметрами и есть функция, которая присваивает одной из переменных обьекта конкретное значение в зависимости от того, какое значение примет зависимая переменная обьекта. Например, есть у в обьекте переменная "возраст", которая может колебаться в диапазовне от 5 до 60 лет. А есть переменная "взрослый", которая должна принимать истинное значение, если возраст равен или больше 18, и ложное - если возраст меньше 18. Для этой задачи я написал небольшую функцию:

```
const ADULT_YES = 1,
      ADULT_NO = 2;

function getAdult(people) {
  if (people.age < 18) {
    people.adult = ADULT_NO;
  } else {
    people.adult = ADULT_YES;
  }
}  

function getRandom(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; //Максимум и минимум включаются
};

{
      gender: newGender,
      fraction: getRandom(0, 6),
      race: getRandom(0, 4),
      age: getRandom(age1, age2),
      adult: getAdult(this),
      socialStats: socStat,
      work: getWorker(this),
      workPlace: 0,
    }
```

Однако, выполняя данный код, переменная "взрослый" всегда возвращает значение "не определен". Подозреваю, что проблема в использовании this, возможно он считывает не тот обьект, в котором находится функция, а может еще что не так. Помогите разобраться, что не так, и как исправить это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном куске кода

```
adult: getAdult(this),
```

идет попытка присвоить свойству adult значение, которое возвращает `getAdult`, однако, данная функция

```
function getAdult(people) {
  if (people.age < 18) {
    people.adult = ADULT_NO;
  } else {
    people.adult = ADULT_YES;
  }
}
```

Ничего не возвращает, поэтому присваивается `undefined`.

Также, передается `this`, который нигде не определяется и поэтому имеет значение глобального объекта.

Для решения нужно либо сделать функцию конструктор, либо воспользоваться свойствами([getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set))

Например:

```js
const ADULT_YES = 1,
  ADULT_NO = 2;

function getAdult(people) {
  if (people.age < 18) {
    return ADULT_NO;
  } else {
    return ADULT_YES;
  }
}

function getRandom(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; //Максимум и минимум включаются
};

var obj = {
  age: getRandom(5, 60),
  get adult() {
    return getAdult(this)
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```